# Permissions not showing on mobile ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qr-code

I am making this QR code reader for this product that I was hired to make
and I found a road block that I am not able to get over. I added the permissions
code with this code snippet: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})` and it works on desktop (I can even make it smaller screen and it still works, the popup shows up and everything) but on mobile I go to the public url that I got once I did `npm start` (which was 192.168.1.126:3000) and I get a full white screen straight away. Not sure what I can do to fix it, I've been trying for around 3 days so far and coming here is kind of my last resort. Has anyone ever run into such problem? Is permissions something you can't do on mobile when you are on devevelopment? Do you know how to fix it?

P.S. I tried 3 different mobile browsers and around 4 qr code scanner packages and they all do the same

Comment: Maybe lack of mobile browser's (app) support for this feature could be the reason, even im not sure does mobile browsers have mic and cam/video support?
If they support that feature, then mobile browser/app's permission could be a problem.

Comment: @douscriptist they have that permission from what I know. You can use teams and skype from web on mobile. You usually get a prompt that says allow or deny